# JavaScript/TypeScript: How to pass arguments of an array individually to a function?

Tags: polkadot-js, smart-contract, javascript, typescript

I want to dynamically call contract functions. The only problem with this is,
that all of the functions have a different amount of variables.
As of now, the function looks like this:

```
async call(message: string, args, accountId: string){

    const provider =  new WsProvider(this.providerAddress)
    const api = await ApiPromise.create({ provider })
    const contract = new ContractPromise(api, this.abi, this.contractAddress)

    const gasLimit = this.gasLimit
    const storageDepositLimit = this.storageDepositLimit
            

    if(args.length == 1) {
         const { gasRequired, storageDeposit, result, output } = await   contract.query[message](
                    accountId,
                    {
                     gasLimit,
                     storageDepositLimit,
                    },
                    args[0]
                )
                    return{gasRequired, storageDeposit, result, output}
     }
}
```

'args' is an array of the arguments passed to the contract query.
Is it possible to loop through all args in the contract call,instead of calling them all individually using their index?

Comment: You can use the JS spread operator, e.g. `contract.query[message](accountId, <opts>, ...args)`

Answer (score 1):

An option to do this is using apply. The code would look like this:

```
const { gasRequired, storageDeposit, result, output } = await contract.query[message].apply(null, [
       accountId,
       {
           gasLimit,
           storageDepositLimit,
       },
       ...this.args
])
```